# Plotting Bar Chart with X, Y and Z axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have below data,

[image]

Am trying to plot bar chart in matplotlib using below code,

```
    pyplot.bar(gender, ward, width, color='orange')
    pyplot.bar(count, gender, width, color='tomato')
```

Below is the result,
[image]

My expectation is as below which is created in excel,

[image]

Any suggestion will be helpful to get the same in matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that very easy with [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Ward', y='Count', hue='Gender', palette=['orange', 'tomato']) #df is the dataframe you showed as example
```

[image]

Without seaborn, you could pivot your data before plotting it. Like this:

```
df.pivot(index='Ward', columns='Gender', values='Count').plot(kind='bar', color=['orange', 'tomato'])
plt.ylabel('Count')
```